# Create a div inside div with same class name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following structure of my HTML code:

```
<div id="bb-bookblock" class="bb-bookblock">
    <div class="bb-item">
        <div class="bb-custom-side">
            Hello
        </div>
        <div class="bb-custom-side">
            <button id="add">Click Here to add The page</button>    
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bb-item">
        <div class="bb-custom-side">
            <p>This is first page</p>
        </div>
        <div class="bb-custom-side">
            <p>Hello</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bb-item">
        <div class="bb-custom-side">
            <p>This is second Page</p>
        </div>
        <div class="bb-custom-side">
            <p>This is last page</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I click on button with `id=add` I want to create the a new div after the last `bb-item` div with same two div inside it having class name `bb-custom-side`.
I know how to create the div using `createElement` and it a class, but I don't know how to create the sub div inside that newly created div. Can I associate with the last child or similar concept?

So after click event I want my HTML to be something like this:

```
<div id="bb-bookblock" class="bb-bookblock">
    <div class="bb-item">
        <div class="bb-custom-side">
            Hello
        </div>
        <div class="bb-custom-side">
            <button id="add">Click Here to add The page</button>    
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bb-item">
        <div class="bb-custom-side">
            <p>This is first page</p>
        </div>
        <div class="bb-custom-side">
            <p>Hello</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bb-item">
        <div class="bb-custom-side">
            <p>This is second Page</p>
        </div>
        <div class="bb-custom-side">
            <p>This is last page</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <--Newly created div-->
    <div class="bb-item">
        <div class="bb-custom-side">
            new div
        </div>
        <div class="bb-custom-side">
            new div 2
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`clone()`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) to create copy of div elements and append it to main div:

```
$("#add").click(function(){
    var clonedDiv = $(".bb-item:last").clone();
    clonedDiv = clonedDiv.find("div.bb-custom-side p").text("This is third Page");
    $("#bb-bookblock").append(clonedDiv);
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/NrnYM/1/)**</kbd>

**NOTE:** I just updated text for last div (This is third Page). You have to put it in loop to increase number.

Comment: And then how to change the content of the newly cloned div?

Comment: @user2831921 Updated. check fiddle.

Comment: Thanx a lot!!Got it!!But can u help me how to actually add those div so that I can see my file to be updated with a new div!!The third page goes up if I refresh my content.Is thier any way to do it?I want my file to be updated because its new content to be displayed to user in flipBook.

Comment: If you are talking about updating a data file, that is a little more complex.  You are going to either have to submit the new data through a form or update it with an Ajax call . . . that's a completely separate topic.   :)

Comment: yeah I can try it with ajax call!!I have used it!!Thanx a lot

Comment: I m not understanding how to do it with ajax.When i click on button a new div comes out but next time when i refresh a page or without refresh a new div should already be present!!How can I do that?Thanx in advance.

Comment: you may want to search around for other AJAX questions or ask your own. refreshing "forgets" the changes you've made in your browser; you have to save those changes back to the server, but that opens up a whole line of questions about security and your particular implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
   $('#add').on('click',function(){
        $('.bb-item').eq(1).append($('.bb-item:last-child').html());
    });

                      OR

    $('#add').click(function(){
        $('.bb-item').eq(1).append($('.bb-item:last-child').html());
    });
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CX85Y/)**

Answer (score 2):

You can try this.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#add").click(function () {
        $("#bb-bookblock").append('<div class="bb-item"><div class="bb-custom-side"> new div</div><div class="bb-custom-side">new div 2</div></div>');
    });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/v65X5/9/)

Answer (score 2):

This may not appeal to everyone, but, personally, I tend to like "blank slates" for my cloning.

If it were me, I would do this:

```
var $baseItem = $("<div></div>").addClass("bb-item");
var $baseCustomSide = $("<div></div>").addClass("bb-custom-side");

$("#add").click(function(){
    var $newItem = $baseItem.clone();

    $newItem.append($baseCustomSide.clone().html("your_first_content_here"));
    $newItem.append($baseCustomSide.clone().html("your_second_content_here"));

    $("#bb-bookblock").append($newItem);
});
```

Unless there is a really good reason to reuse an existing element, I find you end up having to be a lot more complex to "scrub" the existing content from the clone . . . using a blank template always seems more clean to me.